Absolute value of elements of b=Ax and the minimum singular value of A
For $b=Ax$, is there a way to relate the minimum absolute value of the element of $b$, $\min|b_i|$, and the minimum singular value, $\sigma_\text{min}$, of $A$?
What I want is something like: $\sigma_\text{min}$ gives an upper bound of $\min|b_i|$. Is it possible?

This is impossible because $b$ scales with $x$, so there is no bound independent of $x$; and, if $A$ is singular, then there might be no bound even after $x$ is specified (e.g., $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $x = \vec0$).

even if you restrain $x$ to be of norm one, you can take a square singular $A$ and a vector $x$ such that no element of $Ax$ is zero
